# How to have a delete flow in Mule Application?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I just came to know about this Mule ESB and started playing with it. I checked few youtube videos and trying a basic flow which will just 1. delete a file or folder, 2. copy a file from source to destination, 3. move a file from source to destination, 4. logs a message, but unfortunately none is working.
It Says my application deployed without any errors but nothing is working
Below is generated XML when i drag n drop a "file copy" from the palatte.

```
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <flow name="sampleFlow" doc:id="06ea9943-8a7f-46a2-807a-1dff0f99d05b" >
        <file:delete doc:name="Delete" doc:id="16275baf-bbcd-437a-b511-faee072e9a17" path="D:\source"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Below is the console log:

```
MULE_HOME is set to E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule
MULE_BASE is set to E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.35
  Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
  Licensed to MuleSoft Inc. for Mule Runtime Enterprise Edition

Launching a JVM...

Running Mule on testing mode

Starting the Mule Container...
WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO  2018-08-20 14:07:44,466 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer: 
**********************************************************************
* Server started: 8/20/18 2:07 PM                                    *
* JDK: 1.8.0_152 (mixed mode)                                        *
* JDK properties:                                                    *
*  - java.vendor = Oracle Corporation                                *
*  - java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM                *
*  - java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre              *
* OS: Windows 10 -  (10.0, amd64)                                    *
* Host: HYDWKW532 (172.16.170.82)                                    *
* Mule services:                                                     *
*  - api-gateway-contract-service-1.0.1-mule-service.jar             *
*  - mule-service-http-ee-1.1.3-mule-service.jar                     *
*  - mule-service-oauth-1.1.2-mule-service.jar                       *
*  - mule-service-scheduler-1.1.6-mule-service.jar                   *
*  - mule-service-soap-1.1.6-mule-service.jar                        *
*  - mule-service-weave-ee-2.1.4-mule-service.jar                    *
* Mule server plugins:                                               *
*  - mule-agent-plugin                                               *
*  - mule-debugger-mule-server-plugin                                *
* Applied patches:                                                   *
* Mule system properties:                                            *
*  - mule.testingMode =                                              *
* - mule.base =                                                      *
* E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.e *
* e_7.2.1.201808031757\mule                                          *
* - mule.home =                                                      *
* E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.e *
* e_7.2.1.201808031757\mule                                          *
*  - mule.forceConsoleLog =                                          *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,124 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.3 created.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,124 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore: RAMJobStore initialized.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,125 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.3) '[MuleRuntime].' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,125 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.3
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,125 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler [MuleRuntime]._$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,174 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.service.internal.manager.MuleServiceManager: 
**********************************************************************
* Started DefaultSchedulerService                                    *
*                                                                    *
* Resolved configuration values:                                     *
*                                                                    *
* gracefulShutdownTimeout:       15000 ms                            *
* cpuLight.threadPool.size:      8                                   *
* cpuLight.workQueue.size:       0                                   *
* io.threadPool.maxSize:         148                                 *
* io.threadPool.threadKeepAlive: 30000 ms                            *
* cpuIntensive.threadPool.size:  8                                   *
* cpuIntensive.workQueue.size:   1024                                *
*                                                                    *
* These can be modified by editing 'conf/scheduler-pools.conf'       *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,483 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Initializing core extensions
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,519 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterTicketFileLoader: E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.mule\mule-cluster.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
WARN  2018-08-20 14:08:06,519 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.HazelcastClusterCoreExtension: No cluster ID was specified -- High Availability will be disabled:
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,520 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.HazelcastClusterCoreExtension@3c04c922' initialized
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,534 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.factory.ServerPluginDescriptorFactory: Creating plugin from folder E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\server-plugins\mule-agent-plugin
INFO  2018-08- INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,594 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentPlugin: Mule agent keystore file does not exits in E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\conf\mule-agent.jks.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:06,656 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentPlugin: Starting Mule Agent Version: null ; null
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:09,320 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Registering plugin: mule-agent-plugin
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:09,326 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Registering plugin: mule-debugger-server-plugin
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:09,376 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.ServerPluginCoreExtension@29cdb898' initialized
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:09,471 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.deployment.ApiDeploymentCoreExtension@38ef7f42' initialized
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,066 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.analytics.AnalyticsCoreExtension@5dffc24b' initialized
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,066 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Starting core extensions
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,066 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.HazelcastClusterCoreExtension@3c04c922' started
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,066 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Starting plugin: mule-agent-plugin
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,076 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.util.DefaultLicenseService: Mule EE evaluation version. Enabling Mule Agent usage.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,077 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentTransportManager: Initializing transport: RestAgentTransport
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,103 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @27500ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
WARN  2018-08-20 14:08:10,111 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.rest.AgentRestLayer: REST Agent transport is starting with no security
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,232 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentTransportManager: RestAgentTransport initialised
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,233 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentTransportManager: Skipping initialization of transport WebSocketAgentTransport
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,485 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_152-b16
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,588 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,595 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,595 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:10,597 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,168 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@595b55a3{/,file:///E:/Personal/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757/mule/bin/,AVAILABLE}
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,168 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @28568ms
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,176 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.AgentTransportManager: RestAgentTransport started
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,227 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.services.AgentStudioManagementService: Starting Studio Management Service
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,228 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.services.AgentStudioManagementService: Studio Checker is running
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,230 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.plugin.ServerPluginCoreExtension@29cdb898' started
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,231 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.deployment.ApiDeploymentCoreExtension@38ef7f42' started
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,231 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManagerServer: Core extension 'com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.analytics.AnalyticsCoreExtension@5dffc24b' started
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,239 [ServoPollScheduler-0] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: Skipping the initialization of the mule.agent.nagios.jmx.internal.handler Internal Handler because it's disabled.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,321 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ================== New Exploded Artifact: default
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,405 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: Initializing the domain.deployment.notification.internal.message.handler ...
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,405 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: domain.deployment.notification.internal.message.handler initialized successfully.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,432 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New domain 'default'                                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,432 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing domain 'default'                            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,810 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension ee (version: 4.1.3 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:11,822 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension mule (version: 4.1.3 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,118 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,119 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext: default (DOMAIN)
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,235 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.processor.MuleInjectorProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,237 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.DefaultMuleConfiguration]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,833 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\default\queue-tx-log\tx1.log and E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\default\queue-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:12,839 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\default\queue-xa-tx-log\tx1.log and E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\default\queue-xa-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,360 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.api.el.AbstractBindingContextBuilderFactory: Loaded BindingContextBuilderFactory implementation 'org.mule.runtime.core.api.el.DefaultBindingContextBuilderFactory' from classloader 'org.mule.runtime.module.reboot.internal.MuleContainerSystemClassLoader@b799ae7'
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,450 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Starting ResourceManager
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,450 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Started ResourceManager
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,467 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Domain: default                                                    *
* OS encoding: windows-1252, Mule encoding: UTF-8                    *
*                                                                    *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,469 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
**********************************************************************
* Started domain 'default'                                           *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:16,472 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\apps\sample.jar
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:17,458 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: Initializing the application.deployment.notification.internal.message.handler ...
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:17,459 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: application.deployment.notification.internal.message.handler initialized successfully.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:17,480 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'sample'                                         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:17,480 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'sample'                                +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:21,307 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension ee (version: 4.1.3 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:21,309 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension mule (version: 4.1.3 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,080 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension Sockets (version: 1.1.1 vendor: Mulesoft )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,082 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension HTTP (version: 1.3.1 vendor: Mulesoft )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,088 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension File (version: 1.1.3 vendor: Mulesoft )
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,818 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,818 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext: sample (APP)
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,871 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.processor.MuleInjectorProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:22,873 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.DefaultMuleConfiguration]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,144 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\sample\queue-tx-log\tx1.log and E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\sample\queue-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,144 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\sample\queue-xa-tx-log\tx1.log and E:\Personal\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.3.ee_7.2.1.201808031757\mule\.\.mule\sample\queue-xa-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,154 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Initialising flow: sampleFlow
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,214 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.api.message.AbstractMuleMessageBuilderFactory: Loaded MuleMessageBuilderFactory implementation 'org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.DefaultMessageBuilderFactory' from classloader 'org.mule.runtime.module.reboot.internal.MuleContainerSystemClassLoader@b799ae7'
WARN  2018-08-20 14:08:23,307 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.client.provider.ApiPlatformClientProvider: Client ID or Client Secret were not provided. API Platform client is DISABLED.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,317 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Starting app 'sample'                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,317 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Starting ResourceManager
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,317 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Started ResourceManager
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,323 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow: sampleFlow
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,527 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: Initializing the flow.status.notification.internal.message.handler ...
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,527 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: flow.status.notification.internal.message.handler initialized successfully.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,530 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Application: sample                                                *
* OS encoding: windows-1252, Mule encoding: UTF-8                    *
*                                                                    *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,532 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
**********************************************************************
* Started app 'sample'                                               *
* Application plugins:                                               *
* - File Common Plugin                                               *
* (mule-module-file-extension-common-1.1.1-mule-plugin)              *
*  - Sockets (mule-sockets-connector-1.1.1-mule-plugin)              *
*  - File (mule-file-connector-1.1.3-mule-plugin)                    *
*  - HTTP (mule-http-connector-1.3.1-mule-plugin)                    *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,537 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: Initializing the scheduling.notification.internal.message.handler ...
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,537 [WrapperListener_start_runner] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.postconfigure.DefaultPostConfigureRunner: scheduling.notification.internal.message.handler initialized successfully.
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,540 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,562 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@4f790076{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:52057}
INFO  2018-08-20 14:08:23,563 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* sample                                        * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am using Latest AnyPoint Studio.Version: 7.2.1 (java 8)
Note: The youtube video is 2 years older so might be a older Mule Version.

Comment: You're using Mule 4 and the tutorial is for Mule 3. You can still download 3 on the MuleSoft website if you want to try that, but these kinds of operations are easier in 4. They have better file support, now.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to trigger the flow you created. You need to start the flow somehow. You could use a scheduler to trigger at a given time, an HTTP Listener to wait for an HTTP request, listen to a queue, be called from another flow, etc. The flow will not start by itself. The component that starts a flow is called a message source.
For starters the HTTP Listener is a good choice: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http-listener-ref